# Firebase Firestore FieldValue.arrayRemove not working in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have a collection named favorites and what I want is adding and removing products to this collection. My add part is working but when I use FieldValue.arrayRemove as same as I used in add, it does not work. What can be the reason of this?

```
 onPressed: () async {
                    DocumentReference ref = firestore.collection('favorites').doc(currentUser.uid);
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = await ref.get();
                    List favs = doc.data()["favs"];
                    if (favs.contains(widget.productId) == true) {
                      ref.update({
                        "favs": FieldValue.arrayRemove([
                          {
                            "productId": widget.productId,
                            "name": widget.productDetailsName,
                          }
                        ])
                      });
                    } else {
                      ref.update({
                        "favs": FieldValue.arrayUnion([
                          {
                            "productId": widget.productId,
                            "name": widget.productDetailsName,
                          }
                        ])
                      });
                    }
                  }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with hard-coded values `"Blazer"` and `"Ceket"`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did it but its same. There isnt any error

Comment: Interesting, because that means the database doesn't see it as an exact match. I'm not sure why that is, although it would mean that doing an `arrayUnion` with the same values should logically add an extra entry to the array field. Might be worth testing that to see if it is consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a for loop. I check one by one if the product id exists in the favs. If yes it deletes it

```
onPressed: () async {
                    DocumentReference ref =
                        firestore.collection('favorites').doc(currentUser.uid);
                    DocumentSnapshot doc = await ref.get();
                    List favs = doc.data()["favs"];
                    liked = !liked;
                    int count = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
                      if (favs[i]["productId"] == widget.productId) {
                        ref.update({
                          "favs": FieldValue.arrayRemove([
                            {
                              "productId": widget.productId,
                              "name": widget.productDetailsName,
                              "image": widget.productDetailsImage,
                              "price": widget.productDetailsPrice,
                            }
                          ])
                        });
                        count = 1;
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                    if (count == 0) {
                      ref.update({
                        "favs": FieldValue.arrayUnion([
                          {
                            "productId": widget.productId,
                            "name": widget.productDetailsName,
                            "image": widget.productDetailsImage,
                            "price": widget.productDetailsPrice,
                          }
                        ])
                      });
                    }
                  },
```